# How to find how many bits are there in the logical address?

Tags: operating-system

Consider a logical address space of 64-pages of 2048 words each, mapped onto a physical memory of 32 frames.

how do i find how many bits are there in the logical address and physical address?
please explain.

Comment: Depends on what "word" means.

Comment: If they are bytes then 2^11 = 2048 thus you need 11 bits for the offset in each page. 2^6 = 64 thus you'll need 6 extra bits on top of the first 11 to select the page in the page table (the index). This gives 17 bits in total for the logical address. This assumes only one level of page tables and 8 bits words.

Comment: For physical, same process: 2^11 = 2048 and 2^5 = 32 thus 16 bits.

Comment: Normally, word refers to the addressable unit of the processor (often 1 byte). I guess the answer above is accurate for any word size (if I'm correct).